# GLSL 1.50: "in int" not legal in OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, osx-mountain-lion, opengl-3

This fragment shader code compiles in Windows, but throws an error in OS X (Mountain Lion, using a 3.2 core context).

```
#version 150 core
in int vinstance_id;
uniform uint object_id[16];
out uint id_map;

void main() {
    id_map = object_id[vinstance_id];
}
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: 0:2: int can't be an in in the fragment shader
```

I don't think that's right: In the [GLSL 1.50 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.1.50.09.pdf), section 4.3.4 says about fragment shaders:

> Fragment inputs can only be signed and unsigned integers and integer vectors, float ...

Is this a driver bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you didn't read the spec thoroughly.

> Fragment shader inputs that are signed or unsigned integers or integer vectors must be qualified
>   with the interpolation qualifier **flat**.

(Roughly in the middle of page 32 of linked document, if anyone wants to verify)

Comment: Ouch...in the very next sentence, too.

Comment: It stays the same up to `4.3`, again if anyone's interested.